# Rails: validation get bypassed when using before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, before-save

When creating RecommendPost, user enter a `video_url`, which is a youtube video link
and triggers `before_save :get_video_id`, which is to process the `video_url` to get the `video_id`

For example, user creates `@recommend_post`, fill in `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9ITLdmfdLI`, and then `:get_video_id` is triggered, and then we get the video_id `R9ITLdmfdLI`. At the end, all is saved into the @recommend_post

The problem is that, `validates_uniqueness_of :video_id` is not working here. (I want a youtube video could only be recommended once. ) I guess the validation is bypassed by the before_save method?

And how to validate the `video_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before_save` is called and `video_id` is populated **after validations are ran**. In this case, you are validating the uniqueness of *nil*, which will pass if `:allow_nil => true`.

Use the `before_validate` callback to populate `video_id` *before* validating.